# Access - Finding duplicates between 2 tables between 2 dates

Tags: ms-access

I need your help in access how to count the duplicated during certain period

Table One : Unique Values

| Number | Close Time | Max Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1110 | 01-11-2022 8:47:00 AM | 01-12-2022 8:47:00 AM |
| 1111 | 02-11-2022 8:47:00 AM | 02-12-2022 8:47:00 AM |
| 1112 | 03-11-2022 8:47:00 AM | 03-12-2022 8:47:00 AM |

Table Two : Contain the unique value and duplicated Value

```
Number  Close Time
1110    01-11-22 8:47
1110    02-11-22 8:47
1110    03-11-22 8:47
1111    02-11-22 8:47
1111    05-11-22 8:47
1111    06-12-22 8:47
1112    03-11-22 8:47
1112    08-12-22 8:47
1112    09-12-22 8:47
```

i need 2 types of result
first one include the value im looking for like this

```
Result  Count
1110    3
1111    2
1112    1
```

and the second type exclude the value im looking for

```
Result  Count
1110    2
1111    1
1112    0
```

i can do it in excel using =countifs but now im working on huge data ( millions of records ) and most of the data sent on access files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XyB4.png)

i dont know why tables became like this so i added a photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this query will suit you

```
SELECT t3.Num1 AS Num, sum(inResult1) AS CountInclude, sum(inResult2) AS CountExclude
FROM 
 (SELECT t1.Number as Num1,t1.CloseTime as CloseTime1,t1.MaxDate
   ,t2.Number as Num2,t2.CloseTime as CloseTime2
   , iif(t2.CloseTime >= t1.CloseTime and t2.CloseTime<=t1.MaxDate,1,0) AS inResult1
   , iif(t2.CloseTime >  t1.CloseTime and t2.CloseTime<=t1.MaxDate,1,0) AS inResult2 
  FROM tableOne AS t1 INNER JOIN tableTwo AS t2 ON t1.Number = t2.Number
 )  AS T3
GROUP BY T3.Num1;
```

You may write "LEFT JOIN", this will be better.

Comment: this code is perfect and work as i needed exactly , one more thing please is there a way to extract the duplicated records in a query so that i would be able to check it

Comment: Please explain, what is "duplicated records"?

Comment: See the first record is occurred 3 times during the assigned time and the second record occurred twice and the last one only appeared once during the assigned time , so other than the count which being generated by the above code, i found out that I'm gonna need the records it self as well .........example Number  Close Time
1110    01-11-22 8:47
1110    02-11-22 8:47
1110    03-11-22 8:47
1111    02-11-22 8:47
1111    05-11-22 8:47
1112    03-11-22 8:47

Comment: i came up with this code  "SELECT tableTwo.Number, tableTwo.CloseTime
FROM tableOne INNER JOIN tableTwo ON tableOne.Number = tableTwo.Number
WHERE tableTwo.CloseTime >= tableOne.CloseTime and tableTwo.CloseTime<=tableOne.CloseTime+30 And tableTwo.Number = tableOne.Number;"
im using +30 instead of making a column for the max date  i tested it on a small data and it works, do u think its ok or there is something i should recheck in this code

Comment: I think, part "AND tableTwo.Number = tableOne.Number" in WHERE clause is needless.  Сondition replacement MaxDate  with  "tableOne.CloseTime+30" - depends on your task.

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable with a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT Number, COUNT(*) 
FROM tableTwo
GROUP BY Number, CloseTime
```

For the second result, just put `COUNT(*)-1`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, i will test it tonight but i want to confirm something with you does this code consider that i don't want tickets exceed the max date to be counted ?

Comment: No, but it will if you add a WHERE clause at the end. Like this: `WHERE closeTime > startDate AND closeTime < endDate`. I don't know if you're using `MaxDate` or `closeTime`, nor what `startDate` and `endDate` you want, so you'll have to fill those out yourself

Comment: i've tested the first part and it work well i will try your the second part as well again thank you very much for helping